# Return only particular relationships (from multiple of one type) between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have: 
two types of nodes: **User**, **Place** 
and relationship between these two: **Rates** (User RATES Place, can rate same place multiple times)

I want to get list of most recent ratings (per user) for particular Place (providing *placeId*) for all users

So from following situation:

```
USER_1 RATES (createdAt: yesterday) PLACE_1
USER_1 RATES (createdAt: today) PLACE_1
USER_2 RATES (createdAt: yesterday) PLACE_1
USER_2 RATES (createdAt: today) PLACE_1
```

I want to retrieve:

```
USER_1 RATES (createdAt: today) PLACE_1
USER_2 RATES (createdAt: today) PLACE_1
```

Is it doable via cypher query or should I rather change logic and mark particular RATES relationship as most recent?

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (u)-[r:RATE]->(p)
With u, r, p
order by r.createdAt desc
with u, collect(r) AS rates, p 
return u, head(rates), p
```

First, get all relations and order them by `createdAt` from most recent to less recent (`DESC`)

Then create a list of rates given by a user to a place with `collect`

Finally, return the first element of each list with `head` to retrieve the most recent rate

Comment: Updated with a better approach